# Does App Engine Search API support transactions?

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, google-search-api

It is not too clear from the documentation if Search API operations can be part of a Datastore transaction. So can we expect the same ACID properties that we expect from Datastore operations in a transaction. And is a Document similar to an Entity in that regard?

From this video it seems that they are part of the transaction:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B7FyU9wW8Y&list=FLcBSmKKUXoPd5yFneNFDv4A#t=1952

If not how do we preserve consistency in large scale applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing your search document is not transactional, but what IS transactional is deferring a task to run later.

You can check if you are in a transaction with `ndb.in_transaction()`, and easily `defer` it like this:

```
class UserModel(ndb.Model):
    ...
    def _post_put_hook(self, future):
        deferred.defer(UserModel.put_search_document,
                       self.username,
                       self.version,
                       _transactional=ndb.in_transaction())
```

You also need to handle retries and failures. [This excellent article](http://sookocheff.com/post/appengine/syncing-search-documents-with-datastore-entities/) has a complete walkthrough and explanation, including simple versioning to protect against failures, retries and dirty reads.

Here is the complete example code from that article:

```
import logging
from google.appengine.api import search
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

class UserModel(ndb.model):

    username = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    version = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def put_search_document(cls, username, version):
        model = ndb.Key(cls, username).get()
        if model:
            if version < model.version:
                logging.warning('Attempting to write stale data. Ignore')
                return

            if version > model.version:
                msg = 'Attempting to write future data. Retry to await consistency.'
                logging.warning(msg)
                raise Exception(msg)

            # Versions match. Update the search document
            document = search.Document(
                doc_id = username,
                fields=[
                   search.TextField(name='username', value=model.username),
                   search.TextField(name='email', value=model.email),
                   search.TextField(name='version', value=model.version),
                   ])
            index = search.Index(name="UserIndex")
            index.put(document)

    def _pre_put_hook(self):
        self.version = self.version + 1

    def _post_put_hook(self, future):
        deferred.defer(UserModel.put_search_document,
                       self.username,
                       self.version,
                       _transactional=ndb.in_transaction())
```

Comment: That article was amazingly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have no idea if this was available at one time, but what they show in the IO video is not available today, at least the datastore "integration". The documentation does not mention the "searchType" parameter, or the "query.matches" function.

So in term of consistency, what I do is just add a post_put hook to my datastore model and index the document there in the search API. I have an handler that indexes a given entity, and in the post_put hook I trigger a task for this handler. Whenever a put() is done on my entity, I know the document in the search index will be updated.

Of course you have to manage yourself the errors you might have during your document creation, but I haven't found a way to do better than that.

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  fieldA = ndb.StringProperty()
  fieldB = ndb.StringProperty()

  def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    # here create document
```

Comment: Thank you brian. I appreciate you implementation of a “post_put_hook”  but I dont see any example of transactions or ACID properties in your code. It would be more interesting to know how you handle the errors you mention during document creation?